# How do I get all the rows in a Smartsheet by sending an API call using the requests package in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, smartsheet-api

I am trying to get just the rows in a smartsheet in a single API call by using the Python requests package instead of the smartsheet SDK. Here is an snippet of my API call to get all the sheets:

```
payload = {'exclude':'nonexistentCells'}
r = requests.get("https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetID}", headers=smartHeaders, params=payload)
```

the headers are my Authentication token and my Content-Type.

I tried to use /rows in my request like so:

```
r = requests.get("https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetID}/rows", headers=smartHeaders, params=payload)
```

, but unfortunately it does not work and I get a 400 level error code 405. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what you mean by “*it does not work*” ? I.e., what’s happening when you submit the request? Do you receive any response or error message?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for letting me know. I adjusted my post and I get a 405 Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/rows), the `rows` section doesn't seem to have any kind of "list" call. You can get, update, and delete rows (and some other unrelated stuff) with a row id, but not getting all rows this way.

I can, however, get the rows from your original call using my own auth and sheetId. Is there an issue with doing it this way? I convert the response into json and pull out `json['rows']`

```
url = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}"
payload={'exclude':'nonexistentCells'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

json = response.json()
rows = json['rows']

print(rows)
print(len(rows))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I am aware of the method you used. However, I want the api to do as much work as possible on it's own so I was wondering if there is a call that gets a list of rows on its own.

Comment: There is no other API call that’ll return the rows for a given sheet. You must use the **Get Sheet** API request as described in this answer (i.e., request URL is `https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}`).